# How to get minimum and maximum values in text file in C#?

Tags: c#

In the text file(test.txt) have value

> "Hi this my code project file"

`Minimum=5` and `maximum=6`

I need out put is

> minimum= 5 ("Hi t)
>
> maximum=6 ("Hi th)
>
> "Hi th

Comment: Not clear. Please post what you have tried and explain better your problem and what you want to achieve

Comment: And can you post what you have tried thus far?

Comment: I think this is all you need 
Open a File into a String -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx
Get a Part of a String -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The comments are for _us_ to ask you for clarification, not for _you_ to provide clarification. Anything you need to add to your question, _add it to the question_ by clicking [the edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38217507/edit) at the bottom of your post.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a function that reads the text files into a stream and then parses it into string variable. Once you have done that you can call stringVariable.substring(0,x) to get the output sub string that you are looking for.

Here is the code demonstrates this idea.

```
  public string void GetSubString(int x)  {
     byte[] buffer;
     FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      try
      {
        int length = (int)fileStream.Length;  // get file length
        var buffer = new byte[length];            // create buffer
        int count;                            // actual number of bytes read
        int sum = 0;                          // total number of bytes read

        // read until Read method returns 0 (end of the stream has been reached)
        while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
          sum += count;  // sum is a buffer offset for next reading
      }
      finally
      {
        fileStream.Close();
      }

    var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(fileStream);

    string sub = str.Substring(0, x);
    return sub;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simpler version of Jeffrey's answer:

The reason the output has a single quote is because you can't have double quotes normally within double quotes and I forgot how to escape them.

```
int min = 5;
int max = 6;
String s = "'Hi this my code project file'";
String minS = s.Substring(0, min);
String maxS = s.Substring(0, max);
Console.WriteLine(minS);
Console.WriteLine(maxS);
```

Comment: Oops, it seems I didn't read Jeffrey's question completely, he says the same but also shows you how to read a file's content.